# reading in a file fails. Says it isnt open

Tags: python

I am reading in 4 CSV files into 4 different objects into memory.  The first 3 times, it works.... but the forth time it fails, saying:  **ValueError: I/O operation on closed file**

I import these:

```
import sys
import time
import random
import csv
import ast
```

Here is my code:

```
csvPath = "../../../MegaBits-Data/"
ConditionType = "MBConditionType.csv"
SpeciesType = "MBMegaBitSpecies.csv"
StatusType = "MBStatusEffect.csv"
MoveType = "MBMoveType.csv"

#loading conditions
print "loading '"+str(csvPath)+str(ConditionType)+"' into Memory"
fpReader = open(str(csvPath)+str(ConditionType))
cr = csv.reader(fpReader)
counter = 0
for row in cr:
    if(counter == 0):
        counter+=1
        continue
    Conditions[row[0]] = {"type":row[1],"when":row[2],"durationRange":row[3],"likelihood":row[4],"likelihoodChange":row[5],"uuid":row[8]}
fpReader.close()
#loading Species
print "loading '"+str(csvPath)+str(SpeciesType)+"' into Memory"
fpReader = open(str(csvPath)+str(SpeciesType))
cr = csv.reader(fpReader)
counter = 0
for row in cr:
    if(counter==0):
        counter+=1
        continue
    Species[row[1]] = MegabitSpecies(row)
fpReader.close()
#loadingStatuses
print "loading '"+str(csvPath)+str(StatusType)+"' into Memory"
fpReader = open(str(csvPath)+str(StatusType))
cr = csv.reader(fpReader)
counter = 0
for row in cr:
    if(counter == 0):
        counter+=1
        continue
    Statuses[row[0]] = {"tar":row[1],"tarVal":row[2],"tarValChange":row[3],"needsTarget":row[4], "tarChanges":row[5], "conditionType":row[6], "uuid":row[7]}
fpReader.close()
#load Moves
```

and the next section fails:

```
print "loading '"+str(csvPath)+str(MoveType)+"' into Memory"
    open(str(csvPath)+str(MoveType)) as fpReader:
#fpReader = open(str(csvPath)+str(MoveType))
        cr = csv.reader(fpReader)
        counter = 0
        for row in cr:
            if(counter==0):
            counter+=1
            continue
        Moves[row[0]] = {"typeObject":row[1],"baseLevel":row[2], "baseAttack":row[3],"baseAccuracy":row[4],"targetsOpponent":row[5],"primaryStatObject":row[6],"spriteSheetName":row[7],"statusEffects":row[8],"uuid":row[9]}
        fpReader.close()
```

It closes fpReader, then opens a new one, and reads it into cr.  I dont see where the file would be closed.

**new Code**

```
with open(str(csvPath)+str(StatusType)) as fpReader:
    #fpReader = open(str(csvPath)+str(StatusType))
    cr = csv.reader(fpReader)
    counter = 0
    for row in cr:
        if(counter == 0):
            counter+=1
            continue
        Statuses[row[0]] = {"tar":row[1],"tarVal":row[2],"tarValChange":row[3],"needsTarget":row[4], "tarChanges":row[5], "conditionType":row[6], "uuid":row[7]}
    fpReader.close()
```

It fails on the line:

```
for row in cr:
```

saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "battleSystem.py", line 312, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "battleSystem.py", line 22, in main
    LoadCSVs()
  File "battleSystem.py", line 62, in LoadCSVs
    for row in cr:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: Would love a reason as to the downvote.  The error is not resolved, and this i feel is a valid question.

Comment: Your question is too lonk and includes much more than is necessary. Please try to ask your question as a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Python luckily makes file I/O much simpler than you're making it.

```
with open(file, mode) as source:
    #do stuff with source
```

You shouldn't have to worry about this kind of stuff if you do file access like this instead.

Comment: That is sort of like:  using in c#/ASP, whereas, it will open the file and use it only for that block of code?

Comment: Exactly, more pythonic, less of a headache and generally cleaner.

Comment: @Fallenreaper: That's right (it also handles exceptions well- if an exception is thrown in the middle of the block, it'll know to close the file before leaving). I'm still curious why you got your problem, as I can't reproduce it. Can you create a short reproducible version that still gives you the closed error?

Comment: Ahhh, ill redo it that way.  Should i source.close() then or is that automatically handled?

Comment: After reimplementing it as such,  (ill edit Post in a sec) it still errors.  Thoughts on how to resolve?

Comment: what is the error? can you copy and paste the error you get after implementing the `with open(file) as infile:`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "battleSystem.py", line 312, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "battleSystem.py", line 22, in main
    LoadCSVs()
  File "battleSystem.py", line 62, in LoadCSVs
    for row in cr:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: **ValueError: I/O operation on closed file**

Comment: @Fallenreaper Could you upload the updated version of the code? It's not super helpful to try debugging old code.

Comment: You should. Update it to use with, that will probably fix the problem by itself. If it doesn't then put the new code up with the new error it throws.

Comment: adjusted it to use this new coding styling.  It still seems to throw that error though. Should i have some sort of try-catch on *source* ?

Comment: @Fallenreaper I don't know, could you actually post the new code?

Comment: Its just rather odd that the first few work, but this one does not.  I dont see any difference with the design.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Post all of the new code, and get rid of the old code. Also you don't call close() on something opened with `with`